# Does uniform convergence of a function sequence imply the convergence of the corresponding level set?

Tags: lebesgue-measure, uniform-convergence

Suppose $f_n(x),f(x)$ are both continuous functions with domain $M\subset R^2$ and codomain $R$, and define $L=\{x:f(x)\geq c\}$ and $L_n=\{x:f_n(x)\geq c\}$. Suppose $\underset{x\in M}{sup}|f_n(x)-f(x)|\rightarrow 0$. Do we have convergence of $L_{n}$ to $L$ in the following sense:

$\mu(L\Delta L_{n})\rightarrow 0$, where $\mu(\cdot)$ denotes the Lebesgue measure and $L\Delta L_{n}$ denotes the symmetric set difference: $L\Delta L_{n}=(L\cap L_{n}^c)\cup( L_{n}\cap L^c)$ (in plain words, the Lebesgue measure of the difference of these two sets vanishes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=0$ and $f_n(x)=-1/n$ for all $x\in M$ and all $n$. Let  $c=0$.  Then $L=M$ but $L_n=\phi$, and $\mu(L\Delta L_n)$ does not converge to $0$. (Unless $\mu(M)=0$.)

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful. What do you think is the essential condition that leads to the non-convergence of $\mu(L\Delta L_n)$ to zero? Is it the fact that at $c=0$, $f(x)=c$ is flat?

Comment: I hesitate to answer because I don't know what applications you have in mind, that is, what "essential" means here.  I took your problem as an attempted variation of the implicit function theorem with attenuated hypothesis list.

Comment: The application I have in mind is a statistics one, that is estimating the level set by plugging in some estimated function.